# Same template method interface applied on base and derived class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a little difficulty to explain the problem clearly in words so i'll start with the code immediately:

```
public interface ITemplate
{
    bool DoSomething(string a);
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoSomeWork(ITemplate subcontractor)
    {
        try {
            //Do some work...
            if(subcontractor.DoSomething("hello"))
            {
                //Do some more work
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException) {/*...*/}
        //catch(Exception2) {/*...*/}
        //catch(Exception3) {/*...*/}
        //catch(Exception4) {/*...*/}
    }
}

public class BaseClass : ITemplate
{
    public void myFunction1()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoSomeWork(this);   
    }

    public bool DoSomething(string a)
    {
        //Some code here
        return true;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ITemplate
{
    public void myFunction2()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoSomeWork(this);   
    }

    public bool DoSomething(string a)
    {
        //Some other code here
        return true;
    }
}
```

With this structure, if i call `myDerivedClass.myFunction1()`, the `worker.DoSomeWork()` function will execute `DerivedClass.DoSomething()`, but i want `BaseClass.DoSomething()` to be executed in that context, how can i do ?

Maybe it is not possible to achieve what i'm trying to do in that context with the template method design pattern.

The initial problem was that i need a method to execute code, but some part of this code is code is variable according on what object called the method.
Is there another way to do that without `if(typeOf(subcontractor) == ...)` which is not a very good practice, i would like the variable part of the code to be stored and executed inside the caller object.

Could i pass a delegate or something in the parameter instead of sending the whole caller object ?? i'm not very used to work with delegate/etc but i think it might be helpful for my problem, am i right ?

thanks
Jonathan

Comment: huh??? Can you check your code...this does not add up to what you are explaining....

Comment: Abstract method declarations are only permitted in abstract classes.

Comment: Your code does not compile for several reasons. It's hard to tell what you mean as-is. Please correct your example.

Comment: The code has been fixed and it compiles now.
I also changed a little the example and added some explanation. 
I hope it is more clear, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please help me, you ask me to correct my code the same day, i do it and then no reply in 2 weeks... :(

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behavior and is how polymorphism works. If you have an instance of the derived class `DerivedClass` and you have overridden a method, say `DoSomething`, then all calls to the method `DoSomething` in the code of the base class will go through the overridden method in the derived class if dealing with an instance of the derived type.

If you wish the code in the base class to be executed, then you need to either not override the method, or call the base class method from the derived class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod() 
    { 
        // Do some stuff...
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do something new...

        // Do the stuff in BaseClass.MyMethod()
        base.MyMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DerivedClass` is an `ITemplate` since it inherits from `BaseClass` which is an `ITemplate`.  You don't need `DerivedClass` to directly implement `ITemplate`.

Also, as said above, the code you posted won't compile.

```
public interface ITemplate
{
    bool DoSomething(string a);
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoSomeWork(ITemplate subcontractor)
    {
        //Do some work...
        if(subcontractor.DoSomething("hello"))
        {
            //Do some more work
        }
    }
}

public BaseClass : ITemplate
{
    public void myFunction1()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoSomeWork(this);   
    }

    public bool DoSomething(string a)
    {
        //Some code here
    }
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void myFunction2()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoSomeWork(this);   
    }
}
```